# After Effects: centering Layer by Expression

Tags: position, expression, adobe, after-effects

Iam trying zo position a Layer by expression. I need exacly the center of the Layer.

```
w=thisComp.width; //x
h=thisComp.height;//y
w2=w/2;
h2=h/2;
??
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i think i got it!

```
var w=thisComp.width;
var h=thisComp.height;
var w2=w/2;
var h2=h/2;
[w2,h2]
```